# Enterprise Library Silverlight Integration Pack Logging app block remote trace listener can't send out log

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

When an unhandled exception happens, A error window will pop up in global unhandled exception handler, in this window, there is a button called Restart, when this button is clicked, I tried to log the error to the remote trace listener to remote server, and restart the application, but it turns out that the log is never sent out successfully when it is followed by an application restart, I make sure the log statement is executed, but seems that the log is not sent out until the button click event handler execution finishes.

And when I split the send log and restart into two buttons, it works well.

I also tried to put either part in another thread, but it still doesn't work.

Pulling my hair for a few days already, anyone can save me? thanks so so so much...

Comment: Will, you may want to post your question under http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/4923/silverlight-integration-pack where a dedicated team of EntLib engineers would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke Write when using the RemoteServiceTraceListener the LogEntry gets placed in a list to be sent to the server.  Every so often a timer runs and sends the items in the list to the server.  This occurs even if SendImmediately is set to True.  If SendImmediately is set to True then the Timer Callback will fire after about 1 second.

So, what is happening is that when you perform a restart you are tearing down the application before it can send the message to the server.  I had hoped that the messages would be stored in Isolated Storage and then sent back to the server after the restart but that doesn't seem to be happening.

I was able to get it to work how I think you would want but it's a bit messy --  perhaps there is a simpler way?

First create an instance of LoggingServiceFactory and then set a callback to Navigate to the app URL.

```cs
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static void Write(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        // Factory is not configured so set config name
        var factory = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LoggingServiceFactory>();
        factory.EndpointConfigurationName = "CustomBinding_ILoggingService";

        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        proxy.Write(logEntry, () =>
        {
            // Set callback Action
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(
                                    new Uri("http://localhost/app.aspx"));
            }); 
        });
    }
}

public static class ILoggingServiceExtension
{
    public static void Write(this ILoggingService proxy, LogEntry logEntry, Action action)
    {
        LogEntryMessage[] messages = new LogEntryMessage[] { logEntry.ToLogEntryMessage() };

        proxy.BeginAdd(messages, r =>
            {
                try
                {
                    proxy.EndAdd(r);
                    if (action != null)
                        action();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (proxy != null)
                    {
                        ((IDisposable)proxy).Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }, null);
    }
}
```

And then write the message through LogHelper:

```cs
var logEntry = new LogEntry() { Message = "Test", Categories = { "default"} };            

LogHelper.Write(logEntry);
```